# Are there any separators in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I usually use comments in order to separate blocks of code in my python programs but I was wondering if there were any special symbols used to make the code more legible. Help?

Comment: If you would like this reopened, please differentiate your question from the marked duplicate. For example, give specific problems / issues (code is helpful here), or *precise* examples which you do not find clear.

Comment: There's comments, there's empty lines... If you need even more separation, cut the code into different functions (the indentation change also serves as a visual separator) or even different modules (a different file is an even more rigorous separator). What else should there be? A "and-now-for-something-completely-different" emoji? :-)